# Why does the TeamCity agent initially perform 1 build

Tags: python, server, teamcity, cicd

I created the first build on TC, everything is fine, it worked, I wanted to create another one with other files, in the same project I create another build, run it and it gets into the queue, and in the build itself it says:

```
There are no idle compatible agents which can run this build
```

What needs to be done so that an agent can perform several builds at once, or how to make another agent. In short, how to solve the problem, I will be grateful for your help.

Comment: You can install multiple agents on one machine, but an agent can only run one job at a time

Comment: And how to install the agent? I am using a server on linux ubuntu

Comment: I don't recommend installing more than one agent to one machine because of the potential performance and resource sharing issues.

Comment: Then how do I run multiple builds if one agent can only run one build (first message)

Comment: @AlexanderPletnev ?

Comment: @qellyka a common practice is to have a pool of agents, not a single one. The size of pool is defined by your requirements and budget.

Comment: @qellyka I expanded my answer a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

TeamCity agents only run one build at a time and that's actually a good thing - your builds are guaranteed to be independent and you don't have to deal with the cache conflicts.

A common practice is to have a pool of agents to provide enough resources for parallel usage. The size of the pool is defined by your requirements, infrastructure capacity, and budget.

The agent setup process is off-topic for StackOverflow so I can only recommend to check out the [official documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/install-and-start-teamcity-agents.html) on this matter.